# How to avoid joining to a same dimension table twice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `task_instances` that has `task_id, end_time , start_time`.

`end_time` and `start_time` links to `time_table` which contains military_hour format (24 hour ranging from 0 -23).

I want to know all the tasks  where `each tasks start time and end_time belong to the same military hour group ( there are 6 groups , each containing 4 hours)`.

```
  select (floor(td1.military_hour/4)*4) as td1_military_hour_group, 
  (floor(td2.military_hour/4)*4) as td2_military_hour_group, wk_id 
  from task_instances t1
  inner join time_table td1 on t1.end_time = td1.time_id
  inner join time_table td2 on t1.start_time = td2.time_id 
  where  td1_military_hour_group = td2_military_hour_group
```

Is it required to join `same time_table twice`. Can we better the query or even the query seems correct?

Comment: Query seems correct to me, join to it twice, any attempt to make it a single join will complicate matters when you get 2 records back from the join, and have to start aggregating.

Comment: @Andrew How to aggregate then. Means how would I avoid duplicates?

Comment: If time_table only contains 24-hour (military_hour) format for each time and group, you should use `TO_CHAR()` to get 24-hour format instead and simply use `floor` of hour to get time group.

Comment: you can use distinct to avoid duplicate or if you want to aggregate then use sum then in group by wk_id

Comment: it would be better if you provider some sample input and outpur data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the derived values `td1_military_hour_group` and `td2_military_hour_group` in the WHERE clause or you'll get an error, e.g. "Unknown column 'td1_military_hour_group' in 'where clause'". You'll need to repeat the calculations in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select wk_id,
       (floor(td1.military_hour/4)*4) as td1_military_hour_group, 
       (floor(td2.military_hour/4)*4) as td2_military_hour_group
  from task_instances t1
  inner join time_table td1
    on t1.end_time = td1.time_id
  inner join time_table td2
    on t1.start_time = td2.time_id 
  where (floor(td1.military_hour/4)*4) = (floor(td2.military_hour/4)*4)
```

Or else use a common table expression:

```
WITH cteTime_groups AS (SELECT time_id,
                               floor(military_hour/4)*4 AS military_hour_group
                          FROM time_table)
select wk_id,
       td1.military_hour_group as td1_military_hour_group, 
       td2.military_hour_group as td2_military_hour_group
  from task_instances t1
  inner join cteTime_groups td1
    on t1.end_time = td1.time_id
  inner join cteTime_groups td2
    on t1.start_time = td2.time_id 
  where td1.military_hour_group = td2.military_hour_group
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cf17/3)